# Difference between using multiple filters and specifying multiple filters in a single "and" clause

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

I am a new to elasticsearch and don't know what is the difference between the two queries. Is it just processing time or are they fundamentally different queries.

```
1) filters : { and: [{
  "bool" : {
    "should" : {
      "term" : {
        "Code" : "1510"
      }
    }
  }
}
,
{
  "bool" : {
    "should" : {
      "term" : {
        "Id" : "Id3"
      }
    }
  }
}] }


2) filter: [{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [{
      "term" : {
        "Code" : "1510"
      },
     "term":{
       "Id":"Id3"}]
     }
   }
 }]
```

Comment: looks like you  have a typo the first query did you intend to use `and` instead of `filters` ?

Comment: @keety Yes thats correct, the syntax might be wrong but I am just trying to understand whether there is any diff between applying 2 different filters and combining them "and" in a single filter. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The queries  in OP are logically equivalent.

However that being said I find 2) to be  intutive , readable and simpler.

Generally for perfomance reasons **`bool`** filters are preferred over **`and`** although for the queries in question I doubt this difference  is perceptible.

Also for the **`and`** filter the query in 1) is better written as follows :

```
    "filter": {
      "and": [
         {
            "term": {
               "Code": "1510"
            }
         },
         {
            "term": {
               "Id": "Id3"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
```